# Reading two streams (main and configs) in sequential in Flink

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have two streams, one is main stream let's say in example of fraud detection I have transactions stream and then I have second stream which is configs, in our example it is rules. So I connect main stream to config stream in order to do processing. But when first time flink starts and we are adding job it starts consuming from transactions and configs stream parallel  and when wants process transaction it sometimes see that there is no config and we have to send transaction to dead letter queue. However, what I want to achieve is, if there is patential config which I could get a bit later I want to get that config first then get transaction in order to process it rather then sending it to dead letter queue. I have the same key for transactions and configs.

long story short, is there a way telling flink when first time job starts try to consume one stream until there isn't new value then start processing main stream? How I can make them kind of sequential?

Answer (score 1):

The recommended way to approach this is to connect the 2 streams and apply a [RichCoFlatMap](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/api/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/api/functions/co/RichCoFlatMapFunction.html) that will allow you to buffer events from `main` while you're waiting to receive the config events.

Check out [this useful section](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.14/docs/learn-flink/etl/#connected-streams) of the Flink tutorials. The very last paragraph actually describes your problem.

> It is important to recognize that you have no control over the order in which the flatMap1 and flatMap2 callbacks are called. These two input streams are racing against each other, and the Flink runtime will do what it wants to regarding consuming events from one stream or the other. In cases where timing and/or ordering matter, you may find it necessary to buffer events in managed Flink state until your application is ready to process them. (Note: if you are truly desperate, it is possible to exert some limited control over the order in which a two-input operator consumes its inputs by using a custom Operator that implements the InputSelectable interface.

So in a nutshell you should connect your 2 streams and have some kind of ListState where you can "buffer" your main elements while waiting to receive the rules. When you receive an element from the config stream, you check whether you had some pending elements "waiting" for that config in your ListState (your buffer). If you do, you can then process these elements and emit them through the collector of your flatmap.

Comment: This infor was useful and in that documentation it says if u require control over stream u could partially manage it using `InputSelectable` which was what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Starting with version 1.16, you can use the [hybrid source](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/connectors/datastream/hybridsource/) support in Flink to read all of once source (configs, in your case) before reading the second source. Though I imagine you'd have to map the events to an `Either<config, transaction>` so that the data stream has consistent record types.

Comment: Thanks. But in case of hybrid source first one should be bounded. In our case we read config until there is nothing new but at any time in future there could be changes. So that is why both stream for us is the same as unbounded